# How do i fix error: Type '()' cannot conform to 'View' and error : Type'Void' cannot conform to 'View'

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, view

```
struct QuePlayers: View {
        @Binding var quedPlayerCount:Int
        @Binding var newPlayerCount:Int
        let QuedPlayersRef:DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference().child("QuedPlayers")
        let playerCountRef:DatabaseReference! = Database.database().reference().child("QuedPlayerCount")
        @EnvironmentObject var viewModel: AuthViewModel
        var body: some View {
            var myUid = self.viewModel.userSession!.uid
            
               

                newPlayerCount = quedPlayerCount + 1
                playerCountRef.setValue(newPlayerCount)
                print("newPlayerCount = \(newPlayerCount)")

                //myUid = self.viewModel.userSession!.uid

                QuedPlayersRef.child("\(quedPlayerCount + 1)").setValue(myUid)
            
        }
    }
```

I would like to make these modifications to variables and set database values. The code from line 64 to line 72 (refer to attached photo) ran perfectly when placed in a button but i need to be able to run those lines automatically

[image]

Let me know if you need any more information

Stated above^^^^^^^^

Comment: I noticed the photo doesn't list the line numbers but it's from newPlayerCount = until the line that starts with QuedPlayerRef

Comment: You have a view model so move the logic to that class instead of letting the view handle it.

Comment: You can't do imperative code like that inside a view's body. Use the suggestion above of moving the logic to a class or consider using a `task` or `onAppear` to run it from the `View`.